# Windows Compressed Folders avoids Mercurial repo folder .hg

Tags: windows, mercurial

Creating a zip file using Send To -> Compressed folder excludes .hg folder on Windows 7. The same behavior is seen in XP. Is it because folder name starts with a dot ?

Mercurial creates .hg folder to hold the repository. Whenever the working folder is zipped, it leaves .hg folder out of compressed .zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 7-zip or another archival utility to compress the files, since Windows doesn't generally like filenames starting with `.`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes zip skips compressing the floders that start with "." on windows below version 7

See : [How does WinXP's "Send to Compressed (zipped) Folder" decide what to include in zip file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152/how-does-winxps-send-to-compressed-zipped-folder-decide-what-to-include-in-z)

I would suggest that you tar the file before you zip it. This way you will ensure that those folders are included. Tar handles them.